# sql Error: ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I know that there may be a solution elsewhere but everywhere I look, the solutions posted provide no help to me. I know what I call basic SQL but this is the first time coming to this problem and using CASE.

```
SELECT CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM map WHERE map="mp" AND showMap="1")
     THEN (SELECT file,id FROM map WHERE map="mp" AND showMap="1" ORDER BY date DESC)
     ELSE (SELECT file,id FROM map WHERE map="mp" ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1)
END
```

By what I have found so far, Error: ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s) means that I can only select one item instead of the two that I want. How can I change this code to let me select both the id and file from the map that I want.

To explain the code more, if map mp has a version that has showMap=1 then select all of those maps, else if map mp does not have a map with showMap=1 then select the 1st map

There will always be at least one map mp.

Answer (score 0):

You can only select one column at a time from the data.

I am thinking this does what you want:

```
SELECT file, id
FROM map
WHERE map = 'mp'
ORDER BY (showMap = '1') DESC,
         date ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

This prioritizes the values using `ORDER BY`, putting the row(s) (if any) with `showMap = '1'` first and then ordering by date.  The query returns the first row.

EDIT:

If you want *all* the maps with `showMap = '1'`, then something a bit more complex:

```
(SELECT file, id
 FROM map
 WHERE map = 'mp' AND showMap = '1'
) UNION ALL
(SELECT file, id
 FROM map
 WHERE map = 'mp' AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM map m2
                   WHERE m2.map = 'mp' and m2.showMap = '1'
                  )
 ORDER BY date ASC
 LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: the 2nd option you gave works mostly, but the order with all showMap='1' is wrong but when showMap != 1 is correct. It also looks like i will need to do some more learning because I do not understand where m2 came from.

Comment: would i just add an order to the 1st select then?

Comment: @Andrew . . . Your question does not specify the ordering of the results.

Comment: i know but the code I posted did, one of the SELECT was ASC and the other DESC